# using override_function to add utf-8 to all of htmlenteties calls

Tags: php, function, utf-8, overriding, runkit

I have an script that i want to change to Persian but this script has written by my colleague and he used `htmlentities`  without `utf-8` as argument.

I decided to use `override_function` and `runkit` , i managed to install `runkit` on my php and it works but cant figure out how to change this

`htmlentities(LABEL__MAIN_INDEX_ADMIN, ENT_QUOTES)`

to

`htmlentities(LABEL__MAIN_INDEX_ADMIN, ENT_QUOTES , "UTF-8")`

i know that i can use override to change htmlentities so when i call it utf-8 will be added automatically !
please help me

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer !

runkit_function_copy('htmlentities','htmlentities2');
runkit_function_redefine ('htmlentities', '$string,$compat=NULL,$enc="UTF-8"', 'return htmlentities2($string,$compat,$enc);');

this works like charm !!
thanks anyway !